# Is there an equivalent for "yield break" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, each, null, yield

I wrote the following Ruby code:

```
def myItems
    if @item1
        yield @item1
    end
    if @item2
        yield @item2
    end
end
```

Now I tried to use:

```
myItems.each do |item|
    puts item
end
```

However, when both @item1 and @item2 are nil, I get the error:

```
Error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass>.
```

I would expect an equivalent to "yield break" in C# to prevent this. Does anyone know how this works in Ruby?

Comment: If you can clarify under what circumstances you want to "break" I can edit the answer to further help you with your exact needs.

Comment: I am a beginner with Ruby, so I confused Array with Enumerator. So it was a stupid question, but thanks for the brilliant answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you are trying to do, but I think you want simply:

```
myItems do |item|
  puts item
end
```

Your current code is assuming that the return value of `myItems` is an enumerable (e.g. an array), and under no circumstance (even if your `@item`s are not `nil`) is that the return value.

Alternatively, do either this:

```
# Method that iterates over all items
def eachItem
  [@item1,@item2].compact.each do |item|
    yield item
  end
end

eachItem do |item|
  puts item
end
```

...or this:

```
# Give me an array of all non-nil items
def myItems
  [@item1,@item2].compact
end

myItems.each do |item|
  puts item
end
```

*Note: I've used `camelCase` method names because that's what you have originally, but note that it's idiomatic in Ruby to use `snake_case` instead.*

*Note 2: storing multiple similar items as instance variables instead of as a collection seems less useful than storing the collection itself. However, without knowing your data I cannot suggest a better way to represent this.*